# Sharepoint O365 online creating page problem

Tags: sharepoint-online, page-layout

We have a strange problem, when creating new page using this

[image]

It creates automatically navigation link, that you can´t remove

[image]

Comment: I know there is another way to create page and then there will be no link, but our end users sometimes creates page this way and it creates confusion

Comment: Is this classic experience?

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to Site Settings -> Navigation under Look and Feel, uncheck "Show pages".

[image]

If the "Show pages" is checked, you can only hide the link of pages for users.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

1. Go to `Site Settings`.
2. Select `Navigation` under Look and Feel section.
3. Here you will see to option at the very start `Global Navigation`(which will be shown at the top of page) and `Current Navigation`(shown at left side of the page).
4. Under each option you will `Structural Navigation` under which there is an option to show the pages on navigation as `Show Pages`.
5. Uncheck this `Show Pages` checkbox from where you want to hide this links. Either from Global navigation or Current navigation.

[image]